# How to set file object as ngModel using $setViewValue(file)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am updating the ngModel during file selection, when I tried to set string value it is updating properly.

```
scope : 'A',
require : 'ngModel',
link : function(scope, el, attr, ngModel) {
        el.bind('change', function(e) {
            scope.file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
            scope.ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.file);
            scope.ngModel.$render();
        });
}
```

On saving the page, I will be sending the entire model data to server. This value is becoming undefined.

Can't achieve this, Is there any work around is there

Answer (score 0):

I did added a reader in my change function which reads the contents of the file input box. It may not be the most elegant solution but it worked for me.

```
el.bind('change', function (e) {

    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (ev) {
            // here is your data, add it to your model object
            scope.ngModel.filesrc = ev.target.result;
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks... I have done the same thing :) but I needed to set the file

Comment: what do you mean when you say "I need to set the file"?

Comment: I need to set the file object in the ngModel